# EmberJs new project throws Decorating class property failed

Tags: ember.js

I tried to use ember cli to generate local project, but when visiting localhost:4200, I met below errors:

```
Error occurred:

- While rendering:
  -top-level
    application

Uncaught Error: Decorating class property failed. Please ensure that proposal-class-properties is enabled and runs after the decorators transform.
```

and ember -v gives this:

```
ember-cli: 3.28.4
node: 16.13.1
os: darwin x64
```

Please help to point out the reason.

Thanks

Comment: Here is the issue FYI https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel/issues/423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your package.json change

```
"ember-cli-babel": "^7.26.6"
```

to

```
"ember-cli-babel": "7.26.6"
```

the credit for the answer goes to the Ember community on Discord