# Decorating class property failed - new, clean Ember quickstart project

Tags: ember.js

I have the same issue as here: [EmberJs new project throws Decorating class property failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375138/emberjs-new-project-throws-decorating-class-property-failed) but answer didn't help.

When I create a new clean project via `ember new ember-quickstart` and try to serve it i get error:

```
- While rendering:
  -top-level
    application
Uncaught Error: Decorating class property failed. Please ensure that proposal-class-properties is enabled and runs after the decorators transform.
```

Ember -v gives (same as in the linked question except CPU platform):

```
ember-cli: 3.28.4
node: 16.13.1
os: darwin arm64
```

I'm just learning JS and there is a section about Ember in my course. It's very annoying to get stuck and not being able to move on :(.

EDIT:

Ok, I found the cause, but not the explanation. Problem exist only if I try to work in OneDrive folder. I'd try few other locations (local only) and everything works fine. This looks like a problem due to the Ember save location.

I'd like to use OneDrive because I learn on two computers simultaneously. I use OneDrive daily (I have Windows and Mac computers) and I wouldn't like to change the provider just for this reason.

Comment: when you tried the fix from that question, did you ensure you updated your node_modules (via yarn or npm)?

Comment: @Vadim unfortunately no, but I found the reason, although I did not find an explanation. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think downgrading `ember-cli-babel` will fix this issue for you: `npm i ember-cli-babel@7.26.6`

Relevant GitHub issue here: https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel/issues/423